# TS How to have a contextual type outside of a class instance?

Tags: typescript, this

TS only allows using the `this` type in a class or interface method, but I'm looking for how I can use it or something similar, but anywhere.

Take this (erroneous) example:

```
class TypedArray {
    [index: number]: number;
    length: number;

    static of(...args: number[]): this {
        console.log(this);
        return new this(args);
    }

    static from(args: number[]): this {
        console.log(this);
        return new this(args);
    }

    constructor(args: number[]) {
        for (let i: number = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
            this[i] = args[i];
        }

        this.length = args.length;
    }
}

class Int32Arr extends TypedArray {
    forEach(callback: (n: number) => unknown): void {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.length; ++i) {
            callback(this[i]);
        }
    }

    constructor(args: number[]) {
        super(args);

        console.log("Subclass contrustor called!");
    }
}

const x: Int32Arr = Int32Arr.of(0, 1);

console.log(
    x,
    x instanceof Int32Arr
);
```

The `this` does not refer to `TypedArray` itself, but instead, it refers to the subclass.

It is because of that, that `x` is, in fact, an instance of `Int32Arr`, not `TypedArray`!

How can I make TSC aware of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` types don't work for static members. It's a long standing issue and you can read the full discussion on the [TypeScript GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863).

A suggestion for how you might achieve something similar is as follows (taking inspiration from the GitHub discussion):

```
type Constructor < T > = new ( ...args: any[] ) => T

class TypedArray {
    [index: number]: number;
    length: number;

    static of < T extends TypedArray > (this: Constructor < T >, ...args: number[]): T {
        console.log(this);
        return new this(args);
    }

    static from < T extends TypedArray > (this: Constructor < T >, args: number[]): T {
        console.log(this);
        return new this(args);
    }

    constructor(args: number[]) {
        for (let i: number = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
            this[i] = args[i];
        }

        this.length = args.length;
    }
}

class Int32Arr extends TypedArray {
    forEach(callback: (n: number) => unknown): void {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.length; ++i) {
            callback(this[i]);
        }
    }

    constructor(args: number[]) {
        super(args);

        console.log("Subclass contrustor called!");
    }
}

const x: Int32Arr = Int32Arr.of(0, 1);

console.log(
    x,
    x instanceof Int32Arr
);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6qgHigBUoA%20KAXigQgHcoAKKAOlYENUBzJALijYQgA2gF0oASkrkiAKBmYANmyRJi4CABMAgqlRsQUAN4yopqEICWCDRAAefBOgC2AIwioRD529QBuE2YKEAicwAAWXq7u-gGmKGzAFphQcABmBMRQdsDBGqpE6tq6%20mSM4Ra8sIgoGNi4GSSkADQs7FyVjlGoouJ8JMZmg1CY1XBBzApwnAzlSOL%20Q2aoEMDoqAjUdFCzDBzc87FQAL5yg-GJyamocE4NWbY51vmFOnoG5DNhFXzwyGhYODwhEaLT2HW87h6fSMh0GI2QYwgEymnwqB0WpmWq3Wm3oOzB6LMJ0O8JqANwu3akR8PRhGKgqXqDCCwCgFmp7koUAADL42RkwRNgqEwnyANRiiySAb0syzSxiKhghULDHE%20mzIUhcJcwVBbWiw4nYmKZSqACSCGAAGYAEyve6PPJqSBFN50syM1AAUTYmDCDEwbAUChcfoA1nwGAgOahJBRyOgEOGEHBaAhelAAG5wCwaD2LL2MFn8qi8-mETX6kXiyXS2EYoMhsOYcOopAKwmLE6DdVmUn-OqoSncWO0mWLJDoSDDgkxemkxHI6YAIgAyugXKaVMNEP8UPUm0ENABCFdd44yE3VVn2KCWm323Rch9217MNIMbktACMB3kozjJM0yHLYTSgWyfwCJgEBpPeVpvroMjzEAA)

Comment: Oh, there was an issue about it there, should've searched for it. I was about to make a bug report too...